# Newbie: Trying to understand includeCssFile

Tags: css, include

I'm a newbie to Craft and am working with a raw version of Craft CMS 2.6.2903 on localhost and am trying to understand some of the basics. The problem that I am encountering at the moment is to do with the Twig ***includeCssFile*** command.

I want to create a folder that will contain all my CSS details, so I went to **_layout.html** and moved all the CSS script from between the 
**style** tags into a new script which I saved at **craft/templates/styles/index.css**. I then deleted the **style** tags from _layout.html.

I added this line to the <**head**> section of the **_layout.html** script:

`{% includeCssFile "styles/index.css" %}`

So that the <**head**> section looked like this:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>{% if title is defined %}{{ title }} - {% endif %}{{ siteName }}< /title>
<link rel="home" href="{{ siteUrl }}" />
{% includeCssFile "styles/index.css" %}
</head>
```

and once again the Home page worked perfectly.

The problem occurred after I moved the whole **styles** folder up one level (i.e. to the same level as the *templates* folder).

I changed the calling code to 
{% includeCssFile "../styles/index.css" %}
and refreshed the home page and had lost all the page styling. I played around with removing the '**../**' and changing it to '**./**' and even '**/**' but it still didn't work. When I returned the **styles** folder to the **templates** folder, it all worked okay again.

There have been a couple of similar questions already posted on this group, but they haven't resolved my problem ([link 1](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15662/including-css-js-assets), [link 2](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15264/why-is-news-entry-not-extending-layout))

Can someone please tell me what I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever Craft receives an URL request, [it tries to figure out what resource to serve the client](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing). Among other things, it'll look inside your `templates` folder and try to find the requested resource there – which is why a request to `styles/index.css` works if that file exists inside your templates folder. However, Craft only looks at files in your templates folder when it evaluates the request URL, nowhere else – which is why `../styles/index.css` doesn't work.

In any case, [it's usually a bad idea to serve external resources (CSS, JS files etc) from outside your public web root](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/3093/1098). If you can, put your CSS and JavaScript files somewhere in your public root directory, and make sure you're not using relative URLs for `{% includeCssFile %}` – i.e. you should use `{% includeCssFile '/styles/index.css' %}` if you have a folder called `styles` in your public web root (alongside your `index.php` file).

Another option is to inline your CSS files, in which case you can put the files whereever you want. I recommend [the Inlin plugin](https://github.com/aelvan/Inlin-Craft) for all your inlining needs:

```
<head>
    <style>
        {{ craft.inlin.er('styles/index.css') }}
    </style>
</head>
```

If you want to inline files without a plugin, you can use the Twig `source` function – outlined in [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/12314/1098).

Comment: Thank you @Mats. I placed the **styles** folder inside the **public** folder and used this line

{% includeCssFile "public/styles/index.css" %}

to 'call' it.

Worked like a charm.

Thanks also for the 'inlin' plugin info as well.

Comment: No problem, happy to help out. It might be obvious, but it's also worth mentioning that you don't _have_ to use `includeCssFile` to add an external stylesheet to your markup – a plain old, hard coded `<link>` tag will do just fine (one of the best things about Craft is that it makes no assumptions about your front end). The primary use case for `includeCssFile` is when you want to include a CSS file from inside a [`{% block %}`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html) tag or an included template partial.

Comment: Re 'plain old hard code' - You know what it's like when you've got the chance to use some exciting new (Twig) code. You just 'medically' need to use it :)

The only problem I have with accessing the CSS code via the 'new' method is that when I do a 'Live Preview' within 'Entries', all the CSS code is lost. When I hard-code the CSS code into '_layout.html' (as per original setting), the 'Live Preview' works fine. However, when I use a full URL like this `{% includeCssFile http://localhost/sitename/assets/styles/index.css %}` the Live Preview works fine.

Comment: To resolve my own problem above, this [link](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4728/how-to-set-up-siteurl-to-work-with-both-http-and-https) solves everything. Just place it in the craft/config/general.php script and use it like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ siteUrl }}assets/styles/index.css">`. However, I cannot get it to work in conjunction with the `includeCssFile` command.

Comment: @CraftyCockney i just stumbled across this question and solved your problem by using `{% includeCssFile siteUrl ~ "assets/styles/index.css" %}`

Answer (score 1):

In regards to the includeCssFile issue, I was able to get siteUrl to work by using `{% includeCssFile siteUrl~"css/application.css" %}`.